# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'root'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Am trying to connect MySQL Server with ASP.NET web application and am using below connection string and gettign error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'root'.'`

Please find my connection string from web.config file.

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EmployeeAppDB" connectionString="server=localhost;database=employeedb;user id=root;password=root;"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

Please find my controller class below.

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string query = @"
                        select employeedb.department.DepartmentID, employeedb.department.DepartmentName from employeedb.department";

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeAppDB"].ConnectionString)) 
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.Fill(table); // am getting error in the line `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'root'.'`
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, table);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SqlConnection to connect database while you should use MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand to connect and operate with MySQL Server.

Make sure database name and credentials are correct and connection string looks good.

Moreover you can try below connection string:

```
<add name="EmployeeAppDB" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=employeedb; Uid=root; Pwd=root;Convert Zero Datetime=True;Connection Timeout=60;"/>
```